# Attaching something by way of a hook on Shabbos -- problem of binyan (building)?

Tags: halacha, shabbat

I will pose the question with the following example. Someone on their porch has a wooden beam structure that has on it metal rings that one can attach a swing to by the way of a hook. The swing can be easily attached and detached. Is it [muter](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/591) to "hang" up the swing on Shabbos by attaching the hook to the ring? Is this a problem of "binyan" (building)? Does it depend how long it'll be there fore? Nothing is screwed in or attached with a similar more "permanent" method, rather you press down on the hook and latch it onto the ring.

Update: The following is an image of an eye bolt that is used to hang the swing from. [image: image of eye bolts of different sizes]

There is a chain that has on the end of it a sort of "hook" that will be attached to the eye bolt. The following I'll use as an example however not necessarily this exact thing: [image: image of carabiner]

So again we have a swing with a chain on with sides. At the end of the chain there is the clamp/hook/whatever it's called that will be attached to the eye bolt. I realize the one pictured here sometimes has an option to "screw" it into place, let's say this will be done without screwing (or that it doesn't have that option. From the picture here there doesn't appear to be any "screwing" option. Is this swing muter to hang up on Shabbos? Would it make a difference on how much time it'll be there for?

Comment: How is this different from hanging up a coat? (excluding any issues of laundering or hachana)

Comment: @DoubleAA Maybe it is, maybe it isn't? If I was for sure I wouldn't have asked the question. This is becoming a bit old these types of responses, no? The swing attaches (not just "hung" ... I realized I used the word "hang" but I put it in quotations for a reason and mentioned that it attaches/latches on) on and seemingly will be left there for some time. Does this make any difference? I wouldn't be asking all these questions if I thought it was like a coat!

Comment: I didn't get the scenario. Can you add a picture\sketch? These subjects were on the daf-yomi just a couple of weeks ago (and I learned them yesterday...)

Comment: @Yair I realized a picture of something to describe it would be better, I'll try and locate something and post it.

Comment: I believe the general rule is if something is designed to be installed and removed it can be done on Shabbas provided it is not the first time you are doing it. For more info you can look up the halachas on windows which in those days were installed with fasteners to the frame, not hinges or sliders like we do today.

Answer (score 1):

I would say could be *Boneh* because as you state it is being attached to something that is mounted into the ground. If it were a free standing structure then I'd say otherwise. 
[Simple Description of Boneh](http://www.torahtots.com/torah/39melachot.htm#34)

Also, it is probably Makeh B'Patish which is generally understood as finishing an object ie. performing the action which changes its state from useless to useful. 
[Simple Description of Makeh B'Patish](http://www.torahtots.com/torah/39melachot.htm#38)

Comment: bleuf1shi, thanks for your answer and welcome to Mi Yodeya. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site. All the examples of _bone_ in the page you link to are of things being attached durably, unlike the instant case where it's being hooked on.

Comment: @msh210 ... the issue is that in this case it is being hooked onto something that is extremely sturdy where there is no chance the "hook" could slip out on it's own.